# Cannot connect to my VPN and have client display server IP

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ip, vpn-client

This used to work but no longer seems to. Didn't change anything as far as I know. This is the client .ovpn-file:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1" client
dev tun
proto udp
remote myip 1194
float
comp-lzo adaptive
keepalive 15 60
auth-user-pass
ns-cert-type server
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Cerg
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MY KEY
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
```

It all works if I delete the first line with "push" etc. But that is the important part. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if this server is available? Add `verb 3` to config file and start openvpn manually. What does openvpn tell during start?

Comment: Before I tried your changes I tried with this:

`client
dev tun
proto udp
remote cderdepperte.ddns.net 1194
float
comp-lzo adaptive
keepalive 15 60
auth-user-pass
ns-cert-type server`

and it seems to be working now. I tried this config before but then my IP wasn't changed, and now it is. Not sure, maybe the router has undergone some updates or changes. Anyhow, it works with these settings. I'm just curious as how my IP is changed without the `push "redirect-gateway def1"`